# Problema con selección de datos jsoup

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

*Buenas, otra vez, tengo un problemita con la obtención de los datos de esta [página](https://trantor.is/book/izRrE9d-THDs3CSf) al momento de parsear datos. No termino de entender ¿Cuál es el error? ya que cuando debugeo, se ven los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos mencionados son **autor e idioma**, como se ven en la imagen si me los trae. Pero, al momento de probarlo, se cierra la aplicación. En el `LogCat` sale lo siguiente:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.dafran.booksearch.Activities.Trantor.TrantorDetalleLibro$Content.doInBackground(TrantorDetalleLibro.java:101)
```

Así es como parseo los datos:

```
@Override
    protected ArrayList<TrantorBookDetail> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        trantorDetalleLibros.clear();
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("urlLibro");
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements tit = doc.select("header.row");

            for (Element e : tit) {
                String titulo = e.select("div").select("h1").text();
                Log.d("Items", "Descripcion: " + titulo);

                Elements datos = doc.select("div.row");
                for(Element e1 : datos){
                    String imgUrl = e1.select("div.span4").select("img").attr("src");
                    String autor = e1.select("div.span8").select("div.row").select("div.span5").select("a").get(0).text();
                    String idioma = e1.select("div.span8").select("div.row").select("div.span5").select("a").get(4).text();
                    Log.d("Items", "Descripcion: " + autor + "" + idioma);
                    String descripcion = e1.select("div.span8").select("p").text();
                    String descargaUrl = e1.select("div.span3").select("a.btn.btn-large.btn-inverse").attr("href");
                    String lectorUrl = e1.select("div.span3").select("a.btn.btn-large.btn-warning").attr("href");
                    if(!isNullorEmpty(imgUrl) && !isNullorEmpty(descargaUrl) && !isNullorEmpty(lectorUrl)){
                        imgUrl = "https://trantor.is" + imgUrl;
                        descargaUrl = "https://trantor.is" + descargaUrl;
                        lectorUrl = "https://trantor.is"  + lectorUrl;
                        trantorDetalleLibros.add(new TrantorBookDetail(titulo, imgUrl, autor, idioma, descripcion, descargaUrl, lectorUrl));
                    }
                }
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return trantorDetalleLibros;
    }
```

El error está en estas dos líneas:

```
String autor = e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a").het(0).text();
String idioma = e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a").get(4).text();
```

¿Alguna idea de cuál puede ser la solución?

Adjunto captura del `LogCat:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.dafran.booksearch.Activities.Trantor.TrantorDetalleLibro$Content.doInBackground(TrantorDetalleLibro.java:101)
        at com.dafran.booksearch.Activities.Trantor.TrantorDetalleLibro$Content.doInBackground(TrantorDetalleLibro.java:70)
```

Comment: El código que muestras no podría provocar el problema, revisa en el LogCat en que linea y de que clase se provoca el error, podría ser el Adapter.

Comment: He adjuntado la captura del `LogCat` @Elenasys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las 2 lineas que adjuntaste son distintas a las que estan en el codigo original. En dicho codigo estas intentando acceder a un contenido que no existe en dicho elemento. Si usas esta linea y te da error en el `get(0)`:

```
String autor = e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a").get(0).text();
```

Significa que `e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a")` no tiene elementos.

Siempre deberias chequear si existe el contenido antes de usar get() u otro metodo para obtener datos, como `text()`. Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
String autor = ""; //valor por defecto
if (e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a").size()>0){
   autor = e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a").get(0).text()
}
```

Lo mismo para cualquier elemento que podria aparecer opcionalmente.

Comment: Sí, no me percaté y puse el código de otra actividad. Mis disculpas por ello

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, eso ha solucionado mi problema.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno pues el problema es que no hay elementos, debes validar este caso, en caso de no existir elementos solo dejar el valor de string vacio.

```
                String autor = "";
                if(e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a").size > 0){
                   autor =  e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a").get(0).text();
                }
                String idioma = "";
                if(e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a").size() > 4){
                   idioma = e1.select("div.span8").select("dd").select("a").get(4).text();
                }
```

Comment: Pero, a la hora de llenar el `array` me quedaría array(item, item, autor, idioma. etc) pero autor y título siempre estarán serán `""`